# Minimize Sum of a Quadratic Matrix Form

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

For given PSD symmetric Matrix $Q$ and two real $a$ and $b$ i want to minimize the non linear form defined as:

$$\mathop {\min }\limits_{{\alpha _i},{u_i}} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n = N} {{\alpha _i}u_i^TQ{u_i}}$$

st:
$$\begin{array}{l}
U = [{u_1},{u_2}...,{u_N}]\\
U{U^T} = I\\
0 < a < {\alpha _i} < b
\end{array}$$

Comment: $u_i^\top Qu_i\geq 0$ for all $i$, so you want $\alpha_i = a$ for all $i$.

Comment: also, for $N=1$, $u_1$ is the eigenvector of $Q$ corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue

Answer (score 1):

According to @Surb comments, we need $\alpha_i = a$ for all $i$. 
Thus I reformulate the problem here:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cl}
{\min_{U}} & {a \cdot \operatorname{tr} (U^TQU)} \\
{\mathrm{s.t.}} & {U^TU = I}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $$U = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ \vdots \\ u_N\end{pmatrix}$$.

This is a non-convex problem. Applying the Lagrangian Multiplier Method, we have
\begin{equation}
\max_{V} \min_{U} a \cdot \langle U, QU \rangle - \langle V, U^TU-I \rangle.
\end{equation}
The optimal solution is
\begin{equation}
a \cdot Q\bar{U} = \bar{U}\bar{V}, \quad \bar{U}^T\bar{U} = I.
\end{equation}
Thus $V$ is a diagonal matrix formed from the eigenvalues of $Q/a$. And $U$ is the matrix formed from the eigenvector of $Q$.

In conclusion, if $N < n$, then $V$ is a diagonal matrix formed from the largest $N$ eigenvalues of $Q/a$, and $U$ is the matrix formed from its corresponding eigenvector.